# Will OneDrive sync with my laptop that has less storage space?

Tags: hard-drive, sync, windows-10, onedrive, cloud-storage

I have 1GB on my PC hard disk which I am syncing to OneDrive. If I now login with OneDrive on my Laptop which only has 250GB space, will it sync all my OneDrive contents and run out of space or only pull stuff as and when I open it on the drive on my laptop? Both are running Windows 10.

Also can I share my OneDrive account with another Microsoft account so that my partner can login to the same OneDrive contents using her Microsoft account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose which folders to sync - that is, which will show up in File Explorer and be stored on your disk. Unlike Windows 8.1, you cannot have 'online only' folders/files (i.e. no placeholders).

Someone with a different account can access your OneDrive by right-clicking on the icon in the notification area and clicking 'settings', then clicking 'unlink OneDrive', but bear in mind they will only be able to access your OneDrive and not theirs through File Explorer